# Mysql limitations of columns and speed

Tags: mysql

i have a mysql database server running and want to create tables with 'unlimited' columns ( mutch morge then 1000 ).
is there a storage engine that could provide this ?

if this wouldnt go, i was thinking of splitting tables in blocks of 1000 columns. but is there a way to generate fast querys with selects of multiple columns ( and they arent in the same block )?

Like a view ? or somethink like this ?

Greetings

Comment: Why do you need so many columns?

Comment: Sounds like you should investigate a non-relational database, such as MongoDB. However, it would be best to explain your requirements, as that is *not* the right way to use a relational database!

Comment: If you need so much columns your DB design is most probably wrong.

Answer (score 1):

- There is a hard limit of 4096 columns per table. Continue reading here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/column-count-limit.html
- Use MyISAM engine. its good for quick reads.
- And like you said, you can use multiple table JOINS to create a VIEW. But JOINs are faster in Innodb engine.